# Score only updates once and does not update at all after

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Im having trouble with keeping my score updated when my brownie, (which moves when w is pressed), is pressed. Right now it doubles the score but just stays at 2 points every time you press w after.

heres the script:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(2000, 1000)
wn.bgcolor("black")

brnw = turtle.Turtle()
brnw.goto(-500, 100)
brnw.penup()
brnw.shape("square")
brnw.shapesize(5, 10)
brnw.color("#8A360F")

point_giver = turtle.Turtle()
point_giver.penup()
point_giver.color("#8A360F")
point_giver.goto(-500,100)

points = 1



def Brnw_Animation():
    points =+ 1
    brnw.speed(3)
    brnw.goto(-500, 0)
    brnw.goto(-500, 100)
    if brnw.pos()[1] >= point_giver.pos()[1]:
        score = turtle.Turtle()
        score.penup()
        score.goto(0, 0)
        score.color("green")
        score.write(points, font=('arial', 14, 'bold'))



pressed = wn.onkeypress(Brnw_Animation, 'w')
wn.listen()

while True:
    wn.update()
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a simple typo: `points =+ 1` should be `points += 1`